# Doesn't show data from database Flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a consult to data base but doesn't show the fields, I will appreciate your comments, answers or advices.

Thank you!

```
@clientes.route('/listVentas')
def listventas():
        comprador = db.session.query(Ventas, Clientes, \
        Productos).select_from(Ventas).join(Clientes).join(Productos).all() \
        return render_template('listVentas.html', comprador = comprador)
```

```
<div class="tableFixHead">
        <table class="center">
            <thead>
                <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
                <th scope="col">Factura</th>
                <th scope="col">Cédula Cliente</th>
                <th scope="col">Nombre Cliente</th>
                <th scope="col">Producto</th>
                <th scope="col">Precio</th>
                <th scope="col">Condición</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for venta, cliente in comprador %}
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="row">{{ venta.fechaventa.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') }}</td>
                        <td scope="row">{{ venta.num_vent }}</td>
                        <td scope="row"><a href="#">{{ cliente.ced_id }}</a></td>
                        <td scope="row">{{ cliente.fst_surname }} {{ cliente.fst_name }}</td>
                        <td scope="row">{{ venta.ide_producto }}</td>
                        {% set ventastock = venta.precioVenta | int %} 
                        <td style ="text-align:right" scope="row">{{ "{:,}".format(ventastock) }}</td>
                        <td style ="text-align:right" scope="row">{{ venta.condicion }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I'm tryng to show all the results on the table, but no showing anything of data, just the tablehead

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You're joining 3 tables, but the loop in the template only expects 2 tables. You're missing `producto`.

Comment: `for venta, cliente, producto in comprador`